# Wireless LAN can't connect with network

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, router

I installed a laptop with windows XP for a friend, very old school. There is one problem: it can't connect with my network. If I see the list of networks available, I see 2 types:

- Secured wireless network
- Secured wireless network (WPA)

Is it possible that the driver can only connect with the WPA key? My own network is WPA PSK2.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing [Update for Windows XP (KB893357)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1974) if it's not already installed.

> This update to Windows XP provides support for Wi-Fi Protected Access 2 (WPA2), which is the latest standards-based wireless security solution derived from the IEEE 802.11i standard.

Answer (score 1):

The solution: the driver that i downloaded from the manufacturer was out of date. I went to the website of the WLAN Adapter and run a update from their website